# Merged gulp tasks never fire `end` event

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, stream, gulp

I've got a gulp task that loops through a folder looking for sub folders and outputs a JavaScript file based upon the contents of each folder. Below is a more visual example.

- src

  - assets

    - scripts

      - critical

        - loadCSS.init.js
      - legacy

        - flexibility.init.js
        - picturefill.init.js
      - modern

        - connectivity.js
        - layzr.init.js
        - menu_list.js
        - scroll-hint.init.js
        - slideout.init.js
        - swiper.init.js
      - service-worker

        - service-worker.js

becomes:

- dev

  - assets

    - scripts

      - critical.js
      - legacy.js
      - modern.js
      - service-worker.js

This is achieved by reading the contents of the `src/assets/scripts` directory, then running a loop against each folder (`critical`, `legacy`, `modern`, `service-worker`) and sending the contents of each folder to a Gulp tasks which get merged together with [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream).

All this works great, except that once the tasks are merged back together, I want to trigger a notification if the compilation succeeded. If I try to pipe anything to the merged streams, it doesn't work. It just returns the merged streams, and never continues on.

If I un-promisify my `PROCESS_SCRIPTS` function and don't use merge-stream (i.e. only processing one manually specified folder), it works fine, so I'm at a loss as to what's going on.

Here's my full task:

```
module.exports = {
    scripts(gulp, plugins, ran_tasks, on_error) {
        // task-specific plugins
        const ESLINT  = require("gulp-eslint");
        const WEBPACK = require("webpack-stream");

        // process scripts
        const PROCESS_SCRIPTS = (js_directory, destination_file_name = "modern.js", compare_file_name = "modern.js", source = [global.settings.paths.src + "/assets/scripts/*.js"]) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const WEBPACK_CONFIG = {
                    mode: "development",
                };

                // update webpack config for the current target destination and file name
                WEBPACK_CONFIG.mode   = plugins.argv.dist ? "production" : WEBPACK_CONFIG.mode;
                WEBPACK_CONFIG.output = {
                    filename: destination_file_name
                };

                const TASK = gulp.src(source)
                    // prevent breaking on error
                    .pipe(plugins.plumber({errorHandler: on_error}))
                    // check if source is newer than destination
                    .pipe(plugins.newer(js_directory + "/" + compare_file_name))
                    // lint all scripts
                    .pipe(ESLINT())
                    // print lint errors
                    .pipe(ESLINT.format())
                    // run webpack
                    .pipe(WEBPACK(WEBPACK_CONFIG))
                    // generate a hash and add it to the file name
                    .pipe(plugins.hash({template: "<%= name %>.<%= hash %><%= ext %>"}))
                    // output scripts to compiled directory
                    .pipe(gulp.dest(js_directory))
                    // generate a hash manfiest
                    .pipe(plugins.hash.manifest(".hashmanifest-scripts", {
                        deleteOld: true,
                        sourceDir: js_directory
                    }))
                    // output hash manifest in root
                    .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
                    // reject after errors
                    .on("error", () => {
                        reject(TASK);
                    })
                    // return the task after completion
                    .on("end", () => {
                        resolve(TASK);
                    });
            });
        };

        // scripts task, lints, concatenates, & compresses JS
        return new Promise ((resolve) => {
            // set JS directory
            const JS_DIRECTORY = plugins.argv.dist ? global.settings.paths.dist + "/assets/scripts" : global.settings.paths.dev + "/assets/scripts";

            // set the source directory
            const SOURCE_DIRECTORY = global.settings.paths.src + "/assets/scripts";

            // set up an empty merged stream
            const MERGED_STREAMS = plugins.merge();
            // get the script source folder list
            const SCRIPT_FOLDERS = plugins.fs.readdirSync(SOURCE_DIRECTORY);
            // get the script destination file list
            const SCRIPT_FILES   = plugins.fs.existsSync(JS_DIRECTORY) ? plugins.fs.readdirSync(JS_DIRECTORY) : false;

            // process all the script folders
            const PROCESS_SCRIPT_FOLDERS = () => {
                return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
                    // shift to the next folder
                    const FOLDER_NAME = SCRIPT_FOLDERS.shift();

                    // find the existing destination script file name
                    const FILE_NAME   = SCRIPT_FILES ? SCRIPT_FILES.find((name) => {
                        return name.match(new RegExp(FOLDER_NAME + ".[a-z0-9]{8}.js"));
                    }) : FOLDER_NAME + ".js";

                    // process all scripts, update the stream
                    return PROCESS_SCRIPTS(JS_DIRECTORY, FOLDER_NAME + ".js", FILE_NAME, SOURCE_DIRECTORY + "/" + FOLDER_NAME + "/**/*").then((processed) => {
                        MERGED_STREAMS.add(processed);
                    });
                }).then(() => SCRIPT_FOLDERS.length > 0 ? PROCESS_SCRIPT_FOLDERS() : resolve());
            };

            PROCESS_SCRIPT_FOLDERS().then(() => {
                // wrap up
                return MERGED_STREAMS
                    // prevent breaking on error
                    .pipe(plugins.plumber({
                        errorHandler: on_error,
                    }))
                    // notify that task is complete, if not part of default or watch
                    .pipe(plugins.gulpif(gulp.seq.indexOf("scripts") > gulp.seq.indexOf("default"), plugins.notify({
                        title:   "Success!",
                        message: "Scripts task complete!",
                        onLast:  true,
                    })))
                    // push task to ran_tasks array
                    .on("data", () => {
                        if (ran_tasks.indexOf("scripts") < 0) {
                            ran_tasks.push("scripts");
                        }
                    })
                    // resolve the promise on end
                    .on("end", () => {
                        resolve();
                    });
            });

        });
    }
};
```

Also visible on my GitHub: https://github.com/JacobDB/new-site/blob/master/gulp-tasks/scripts.js

---

**EDIT:** I've tried a few things, I'll detail them here.

1. `console.log("hello world")` never fires after `MERGED_STREAMS.on("data")`, `MERGED_STREAMS.on("error")`, or `MERGED_STREAMS.on("end")`.
2. Moving `const MERGED_STREAMS = plugins.merge();` to a module-level variable (i.e. just after `const WEBPACK = require("webpack-stream")`) does not change the outcome.
3. Doing #2 and then using `MERGED_STREAMS.add(gulp.src(source) ...)` instead of adding the stream after the promise completes does not change the outcome, except when leaving `.pipe(gulp.dist("."))`, which is required to output a `.hashmanifest`, and always marks the task as ran.
4. Disabling `webpack`, `hash`, or `eslint`, in any combination does not make a difference.
5. Changing `PROCESS_SCRIPTS` from returning a promise to return the stream, then processing each folder as individual variables, then merging them manually does appear to correctly trigger the task as ran, but `webpack` can only be run once, so it only outputs one file – `critical.hash.js`. *Note: I haven't tested this method in conjunction with disabling `hash`, which may be causing it to be marked as correctly ran if `.hashmanifest` is always being output.*
6. Splitting the linting step and the webpack step in to separate task *kind of* causes the task to be correctly marked as ran, but only if the `lint` task is not a promise, which results in `unexpected end of stream` errors in the console.

---

**EDIT 2:** Updated with a revised version of my task based on @Louis's advice.

Comment: Nothing looks particularly wrong. The most obvious thing to check is that `MERGED_STREAMS` actually has `.pipe()` and `.on()` methods.

Comment: Yea, that's what's confusing me, it seems fine. `typeof MERGED_STREAMS.on` and `typeof MERGED_STREAMS.pipe` both return `function` so I'm pretty sure that's fine.

Comment: And the `PROCESS_SCRIPT_FOLDERS().then(...)` callback actually fires?

Comment: Yeah, if I put a `console.log()` just after that line it outputs.

Comment: What if you chain `.on( "error", .... reject ...)` similar to what's in PROCESS_SCRIPTS(); does that fire?

Comment: No, exactly the same behavior

Comment: Mmm, mystery. It's got to be something simple. Hopefully someone clever will spot it.

Comment: Yea, I'll keep poking at it when I have time and will report back if I ever figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with the code above. One major issue that makes the code hard to follow and debug is that you use `new Promise` where you don't need it. **Generally, if you have `new Promise` and the logic inside the promise executor will resolve or reject *depending on the result of another promise*, then you don't need to use `new Promise`.**

Sometimes people have code like this:

```
function foo() {
  const a = getValueSynchronously();
  const b = getOtherValueSynchronously();
  return doSomethingAsynchronous(a, b).then(x => x.someMethod());
}
```

Suppose that `doSomethigAsynchronous` returns a promise. The problem with the `foo` function above is that if `getValueSynchronously` and `getOtherValueSynchronously` fail, then `foo` will raise an exception, but if `doSomethingAsynchronous` fails, then it will reject a promise. So code that uses `foo` has to handle synchronous exceptions *and* asynchronous rejections if it wants to handle all possible failures. Sometimes people feel they can fix the issue by causing all failures to be promise rejections:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const a = getValueSynchronously();
    const b = getOtherValueSynchronously();
    doSomethingAsynchronous(a, b).then(x => x.someMethod()).then(resolve, reject);
  });
}
```

In the code above, if `getValueSynchronously` or `getOtherValueSynchronously` fail, that's a promise rejection. But the problem with the code above is that it is easy to get it wrong. You can forget to call `reject` everywhere it is needed. (As a matter of fact, you *do* have this error in your code. **You have nested promises whose rejection won't be propagated up. They are just lost, which means if an error occurs your code will just stop, without you knowing why.**) Or you may be tempted to call `resolve way down in a nested function, which makes the logic hard to follow.

You can just as well do:

```
function foo() {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    const a = getValueSynchronously();
    const b = getOtherValueSynchronously();
    return doSomethingAsynchronous(a, b);
  }).then(x => x.someMethod());
}
```

You can use `Promise.resolve()` to enter the promisified world (hmm... "the promised land?"). In the code above, you do not have to remember to call `reject`. If the code inside the callback to `.then` fails *for any reason*, you get a rejected promise.

I also noticed in a number of places you return a value from the executor function you pass to `new Promise`. Your code would behave exactly the same if you did not use `return` there. To illustrate, this code:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return doSomethingAsynchronous().then(resolve, reject);
  });
}
```

behaves the *exactly* same way as this code:

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doSomethingAsynchronous().then(resolve, reject);
  });
}
```

**The value returned from the executor is ignored. End of story. If you think the value you return from your executors are doing something, then that's incorrect.**

Comment: Thanks, I think I see what you're saying. I'm still relatively new to JavaScript, and entirely self taught, so I appreciate the detailed explanations! I suspected I was over-using both `return` and `new Promise()`; I'll take another look at this tomorrow and report back my results.

Comment: Alright, I removed some of the `new Promise()` and `return` stuff, still no dice, I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Updated my question with a revised task. I suspect where it's going wrong is in the `.then(() => SCRIPT_FOLDERS.length > 0 ? PROCESS_SCRIPT_FOLDERS() : resolve());`, but I'm not sure what needs to change there, as if I remove the `resolve()` it never finishes the task.